# NodeJS - Create a new numbered subdirectory based on the last element of an array based subdir list (Closed)

Tags: node.js, arrays, create-directory

I have this function that reads a specified working directory using `fs.readdir`, which then filters out all files and returns an array based list of the first set of subdirectories within the specified working directory, which then grabs the last element (in my case the last subfolder) from the bottom of the array based list.

This list of subdirectories is always returned in order, it's never jumbled.

The way I'm achieving this is with the following code:

```js
var workDir = 'just/some/folder/location';

// Read the specified working directory 
fs.readdir(workDir, { withFileTypes: true }, (error, files) => {
    if (error) {
        //Throw an error if the folder can't be read
        console.log('Unable to read the Working Directory! \n\n')
        //Print the reason for the error
        console.log('REASON: ' + error);
        return;
            
    } else {
        // Filter out files and return only subdirectories
        var subdirList = files
            .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
            .map((item) => item.name);
        // Get the last subdirectory from the returned list of subdirectories
        var lastFolder = subdirList[subdirList.length -1];
        
        // Function to create a new subdir 
        // Based on the last element/folder
        // Returned by the function, needs to go here
        // But I can't figure it out
    };

});
```

What I want to be able to do now, is create a new numbered subdirectory within the specified working directory based on the output of the function above.

So for example if the function above ends up detecting `folder4` as the last subdirectory, how would I allow it to create `folder5`? or if the function detects `folder5` as the last subdirectory, then how do we allow it to create `folder6` and so on??

It's important to note that in my case, the subdirectories inside of my working Directories will always follow a number pattern of `2 through 1000`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what exactly is blocking you ? You seem to be on the verge of success already !

Comment: Yes that's what bugs me most about this, I've got most of it down, but the only thing I can't do is the part where a numbered folder needs to be created based on what the function determines is the last folder inside the working directory

Comment: So is it how to extract the prefix and number from the directory name ? For that, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827884/split-a-number-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately not what I'm looking for, all this does is extract the number from a string, I need to create a new directory based on the last subfolder returned by the function, so if it returns `folder4` it needs to create `folder5`, the new subdirectory title containing the number must always be 1 up from the last subfolder that was returned by the function

Comment: To create a directory you can use fs.mkdir or fs.mkdirSync , and given the number you extract from the last subfolder name, you should know how to name your new folder. I am still not sure what pieces you are missing

Comment: Yes I'm aware of how to create subdirectories, but in my case the last returned subdirectory could be anything from `folder4` to `folder143` which is what makes this hard, if I were to extract the string from the last subfolder and use this for the new folder it wouldn't work because then there would be duplicates and would result in an overwrite, not unless I can just add 1 to the extracted number from the string and then use that in the title of the new subdirectory

Comment: Ok, that was the point of my question about extracting the prefix and number. Will give you an answer about that as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : You just have to play a bit with the regex pattern, to match your exact requirement. I updated the regex to follow your convetion folder_classes[number].

/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g -> /[a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+/g

To know how to name your new folder from the previous one
If you have a strict convention like this for folder name [folder][number] : folder1, folder2, folder3,etc..

You can use this sample to extract the number from the last folder and increase it

```js
const lastFolderName='folder_class123'
/*
You can use match function with a regex like this
It will give you an array with the prefix string, and the number part as a string
*/
const extract=lastFolderName.match(/[a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+/g)
console.log(extract)
// You should put some control, like is extract array length =2, etc..

// You can convert the extracted string number of the folder as a number
const lastFolderNumber=parseInt(extract[1])

// Same here you can put some business rule, lastFolderNumber less than 1000
const newFolderNumber=lastFolderNumber+1
console.log(`New folder number : ${newFolderNumber}`)
```

This should work for any number after the prefix : folder1, folder10, folder222, etc..

Comment: So it wouldn't work for something like `folder_classes`

Comment: You just need to update the regex, I updated my answer. You can use a lot of different techniques to split the folder name, you just need to extract the number  and the "prefix" properly and after that you are good to go

Comment: Yep this is doing exactly what I need thank you so much

Comment: There are a few instances where the function doesn't continue creating directories, for example if we keep creating directories starting from `folder2/folder_classes2` the function won't create any directories after it reaches the creation of `folder10/folder_classes10`... the same thing happens when we start from `folder10/folder_classes10` and create directories all the way up to `folder99/folder_classes99`, it doesn't continue creating directories after it reaches 99, it just sits there, unless these are starting folders then it works, other than that this function works beautifully.

Comment: Those were the only instances where the function had problems though